# Will GIMP, Inkscape work on ldm / lxde / lubuntu in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, gimp, lxde

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 default. I would like to use `lubuntu-desktop`so that the RAM consumption is less. But I see that it needs `ldm`. I was wondering whether switching from `gdm` to `ldm` will make GIMP, Inkscape and Blender fail. I would like to use these three tools and VLC for playing videos.

Is it safe for me to use

```
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

Will my usual programs work on it  ? Thanks.

Edit 1 :

I  went ahead and tried

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

Everything was fine for some time but now I am getting frequent notifications as seen below

[image]

No matter which option I choose, another one comes in after 2 seconds.

Comment: You can always check on Lubuntu LiveUSB.

Comment: Ya, that is an option. But I want some feedback from someone who actually worked with these apps on `lubuntu-desktop`. Thanks.

Comment: I see no reason why they won't work.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by `ldm` - https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lubuntu-desktop doesn't show a ldm (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ldm) dependency for Lubuntu 18.04 (bionic).   I booted a Lubuntu 18.04 LTS box, and `ldm` is not installed, as Lubuntu 18.04 LTS uses `lightdm` by default (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lightdm ; ldm != lightdm).

Comment: I installed LXDE from some guide. I was presented a choice between lightDM and Gnome Display Manager. I took the choice as lightDM. Possibly because of that, I had popups coming which is asking me to confirm the display resolution. It was so continuous, I deleted the session. Now planning to try afresh if `lubuntu desktop` option will work.

Comment: I'm using Gimp and Blender in Lubuntu on an old 64-bit laptop without issues.

Comment: Will other software work too ? The session I had was using just 800 MB RAM instead of close to 2 GB by Gnome. If it is almost the same and everything will work, I would like to switch to Lubuntu altogether, or at lease use lubuntu DE. Thanks

Comment: To answer your questions about whether GIMP, Inkscape, and Blender will work for you, you need to share your machine's specs. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147150/blender-2-80-system-req-gpu-req to know what Blender's recommended requirements are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works in default 18.04 with Xorg. But had issues with Wayland. Since I am supposed to use LDM, I just wondered whether it would be just like Wayland problems. PS : I use Blender less, it is mainly GIMP and Inkscape.

Comment: What's up with the "Edit 1" part at the end? Sounds like a completely different question. In that case ask a new question and remove that from this one.

Comment: I installed LXDE twice. Everything goes fine. But these frequent popups stop me from using GIMP, Inkscape or even Firefox. It was so annoying that I have removed DE until I can find a fix. I have asked that as a different question.

Comment: `Edit 1` Simply suggests that I have installed LXDE based on community provided info. And the current state of it  ( extended info ).

Answer (score 2):

Yes! GIMP and Inkscape will work on lxde / lubuntu in 18.04!

In linux, you can run any application on any desktop environment (Gnome Shell, Mate, XFCE, LXDE) or even on a bare window manager (i3, openbox), as long as all dependencies are installed. You package manager takes care of installing all dependencies when you install an application.

Comment: Can you comment on Edit 1 as well ? Due to this popup, it is hard to use LXDE. No idea where to turn it off. Thanks.

Comment: This site is "one question at a time". If you have another question, just post a new one.